# How can i convert an ElementFilter Expr in to an Element type in Sparql Using Jena?

Tags: sparql, jena

I have a `Visit` method of `ElementVisitorBase` class. Being in this `Visit` method, I want to get the `Filter` expression of an `Element`; then I want to convert this `Filter` expression to an `Element`, so that i can Walk thru it and find if there is `OPTIONAL` clause inside this `Filter` Expression. I have the code below,

```
public void visit(ElementFilter el) {
    Element ele = (Element) el.getExpr();
    ElementVisitorsub ev = new ElementVisitorsub();
    ElementWalker.walk(ele, ev);
}
```

But I am getting an error which says "Expression can not be converted to element 'ele' ". Also, if I use the `ElementFilter` parameter "el" directly to my `Walker` like this: `ElementWalker.walk(el, ev)`, it is looping to infinity. So, any solutions for this?

Thank you!

```
The Filter expression inside my initial Query is as follows.

FILTER (    (  EXISTS    {
     ?var1  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P276>  ?var5 .
     ?var5  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P31>  ?var6 .
     ?var5 ( <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P361> */ 
<http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P131> *) 
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q5061> .
    OPTIONAL {
     ?var5  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P625>  ?var2 .
    }
   }
 ) 
)
```

Comment: can you show the query please? I'm wondering how your filter looks like and this would make the whole question a bit more understandable for the broader audience. thank you

Comment: given hat the only filter containing OPTIONAL which means a graph pattern can be 'exist', you can check if `el.getEpr` is `instanceof E_Exists` and if so cast it such that you can get an `Element` out of it

Comment: Yes, my query has 'exist' element inside it. and i tried to cast it and it is generating error, indicating that it is not possible to cast Expression to Element. How can i cast it?

Comment: I told you in the comment what to do. You have to cast it to `E_Exists` if it is an `instanceof`. Then you can get the element wrapped inside this